# Internationalization of table fields

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, internationalization, logic

I am learning about database internationalization and have a "small" question.

I have one table named `categories` which have the fields `id`, `name`, `description` among others. And, the table `products` which have the fields `id`, `category_id`, `name`, `description` and others too.

```
categories table
id | name | description | ...others
```

and

```
products table
id | category_id | name | description | ...others
```

I need to Internationalize these (and others) tables. So, the start approach are creating three more tables and change the first ones.

```
languages table
id | name | code

categories table
id | ...others

category_languages table
id | category_id | language_id | name | description

products table
id | category_id | ...others

product_languages table
id | product_id | language_id | name | description
```

Well, the main question is: Have a way to "centralize" the localization in one table? What I am forgetting?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

you can add the label of the translation and the translation in one table and then just add to a new column in every table the label of the translation. You will have one table called translations with id column which could be the label and translation column:

```
id | label | translation | language_id
```

and in every table:

```
id | some columns | translation_label
```

Comment: Where `label` is a `alias` for each translation group?

Comment: if a translation group is a string translated to many languages, yes. It's a unified name for all languages of the translated text.